# 2 column layout (Left column fixed width, right fluid + clear:both)

Tags: html, css, css-float, fluid

Just need help as I have been trying sort this out for ages now.  What I need:

I've got a 2 column layout, where the left column has a fixed width 220px and the right column has a fluid width.

Code is:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <title>Fluid</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { background: #ccc; }
        .wrap      { margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background: #fff; }
        .main      { margin-left: 220px; width: auto }
        .sidebar   { width: 200px; float: left; }
        .main,
        .sidebar   { background: #eee; min-height: 100px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="sidebar">This is the static sidebar</div>
        <div class="main">This is the main, and fluid div</div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

There's no problem at all. When I use a css syntax **clear: both** in the right column, all content after gets moved under the left column. This is a right behaviour and nothing against it.

But I relly need to use clear: both in the way, that it stays just in context of the right column (doesn't get affected by the left column at all, and doesn't move underneath)

Is there any simple get around with retaining a basic float concept of page design?

UPDATE: Please see this link to know what I'm on about as it may be a bit confusing from my description. 
Link: http://jsfiddle.net/k4L5K/1/

Comment: Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/a4xyV/

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's your altered CSS:

```
html, body {
    background: #ccc;
}

.wrap {
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    padding-right:240px;
    background: #fff;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.main {
    margin: 0 -220px 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    float:right;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
}

.main, .sidebar {
    background: #eee; min-height: 100px;
}

.clear { clear:both; }
span { background: yellow }
```

Basically what I've done is change the way your layout is done, so that `.main` div is floated on the right. To do this, we had to add 2 things:

1. A padding of 240px on the `.wrap` div, and
2. A right margin on the `.main` div of -220px to properly align the fluid part of the page.

Because we've floated the `.main` div on the right, the `clear: both;` now only affects content inside the `.main` div, as you want.

You can see a demonstration here: http://jsfiddle.net/6d2qF/1/

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thank you! ;)

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite old but here is the another solution which I've found recently.

We just need to do 2 things:

1. Add `overflow: auto;` to the `.main` div
2. Make sure wrapper preserves document flow by adding `overflow: hidden;` to the `.wrap` div, or adding `.clear` div as the last child of `.wrap` element

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k4L5K/89/

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
     <title>Fluid</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        html, body { background: #ccc; }
        .wrap      { margin: 20px; padding: 20px; background: #fff; }
        .main      { margin-left: 220px; width: auto }
        .sidebar   { width: 200px; }
        .main,
        .sidebar   { background: #eee; min-height: 100px; float: left; }
        .clear {clear:both;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="sidebar">This is the static sidebar</div>
        <div class="main">This is the main, and fluid div</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```